# How to break a xml line into several lines using bash script?

Tags: bash

I'm a beginner in bash script and cannot solve the following problem: I have a file where each line is a xml file. I would like to divide each line into several lines.

For instance, I would like to put the following line:

```
<LumiBlockCollection><Run>201556</Run><LBRange Start="1020" End="1030"/></LumiBlockCollection>
```

into the format:

```
<LumiBlockCollection>
<Run>201556</Run>
<LBRange Start="1020" End="1030"/>
</LumiBlockCollection>
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: How to solve the problem? it's easy if you use an xml parser.

Comment: The script is to be used in different OS. Usually, I use OS X, SL (scientific linux) and Fedora.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, for a **robust solution** that works with varying input data, you should use an **XML parser** for this task:

---

A solution based on **`xmllint`** - `xmllint` is a standard utility on **OS X** and ***some* Linux** distros (e.g., **Fedora**):

```
  echo '<LumiBlockCollection><Run>201556</Run><LBRange Start="1020" End="1030"/></LumiBlockCollection>' \
    | XMLLINT_INDENT= xmllint --format - | tail -n +2
```

If your Linux distro does *not* come with `xmllint`, chances are that it can be installed with your platform's package manager; e.g., on Debian-based distros such as **Ubuntu**:
`sudo apt-get install libxml2-utils`

---

Another solution,  based on third-party utility **[`xmlstarlet`](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/)**:

```
echo '<LumiBlockCollection><Run>201556</Run><LBRange Start="1020" End="1030"/></LumiBlockCollection>' \
  | xmlstarlet fo --omit-decl --noindent
```

Obtaining `xmlstarlet`:

- **OSX**: Install via [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) with `brew install xmlstarlet`
- **Linux**: chances are that it can be installed with your platform's package manager; e.g., on Debian-based distros such as **Ubuntu**: `sudo apt-get install xmlstarlet`

Comment: Hello, I've used your solution and tested in three different OS: OS X, SL (scientific linux) and Fedora. It works! I'm doing the following: instead of using printf %s, I use echo $line in a do while block, because I'm reading from an input file. Thank you!!

Comment: @user3658088: You're welcome; I'm glad to hear it worked - I assume you went with the `xmllint` solution, right?. The `printf %s` wasn't strictly necessary, so I've changed it to `echo` to avoid a distraction (`printf %s` has the advantage that it'll always print the string literally (and without terminating `\n`), whereas `echo`'s behavior can be altered by shell options (interpretation of escape sequences)).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution using `sed`. Note that if you have `CDATA` sections, this will place them on their own line:

```
$ xml='<LumiBlockCollection><Run>201556</Run><LBRange Start="1020" End="1030"/></LumiBlockCollection>'
$ echo $xml | sed 's/></>\n</g'
<LumiBlockCollection>
<Run>201556</Run>
<LBRange Start="1020" End="1030"/>
</LumiBlockCollection>
$
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for helping me. But, your solution doesn't work for me. I've tested in my laptop (OS X) and it put 'n' between '><'.